# Getting Firefox logs in c# using Selenium throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, logging

I am trying to record the log files in Firefox using Selenium in c#;

I have put together a very simple example to try and open a browser and get the logs.

However this is throwing a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' exception on the following line.

> var entries = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);

Can anyone help as to why this is happening and if there is any solution?

Here is the full code

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
            var driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");

            var entries = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you set a breakpoint on that line and used the debugger to see what is null?

Answer (score 2):

I *believe* that this is an unsupported feature, here's the referenced issues:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1161
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/284